# Is it possible to edit the keybindings in Super Meat Boy?

Tags: pc, super-meat-boy

I've recently started playing Super Meat Boy on the PC, but I find that the default control scheme to be rather lacking. I would much prefer to use something other than space for jumping.

Is there anyway for my change the control scheme of Super Meat Boy?

Comment: AutoHotKey?  I don't know if there's a menu option for key bindings, but AutoHotKey works 99.999% of the time, or your *money back*.

Comment: Use a controller, you WILL notice the difference! (just like Super Mario Bros., it plays better with a controller)

Comment: @alexanderpas I would do that if I had a PC controller.

Comment: @Wipqozn: Note that both PS3 and XBox controllers work with PC, so if you have either of those you can use them.  PS3 controllers require [special software](http://www.motioninjoy.com/), and wireless XBox controllers require a special adapter *(wired XBox controllers work without hitch)*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to edit the control mapping, although not in-game. In order to do this you need to edit the file **buttonmap.cfg**. If the game is installed on Steam, it should be located under:

```
Program File > Steam > steamapps > common > super meat boy >buttonmap.cfg
```

The file will look like this:

```
keyboard
{
    up="up";
    down="down";
    left="left";
    right="right";
    jump="space";
    special="shift";
}

gamepad
{
    jump="1";
    special="3";
    useanalog="true";
}
```

Simply edit the corresponding line to change the key bindings. For example:

```
keyboard
{
    up="up";
    down="down";
    left="left";
    right="right";
    jump="z";
    special="x";
}

gamepad
{
    jump="1";
    special="3";
    useanalog="true";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For those on Mac OSX Steam this can be found at the following path. Remember right click and to use show package contents on the

```
$HOME/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/Super Meat Boy/SuperMeatBoy.app/Contents/Resources/buttonmap.cfg
```